# Making Div Hide after its been shown

Tags: html, css

So I have it so far when you click on an image it shows a Div. I just need it so that when you click on the image again and the div is being shown then it will hide.

Here is my code:

Style and script

```
<style type="text/css">
.show{display:block;}
.hide{display:none;}
</style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function showImg()
{
var obj=document.getElementById('calcShow');
obj.className = 'show';
}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<li data-value="iconchange"><img src="modules/icons/icons/calculator.png" width="65"  onclick = "showImg()" class="calculator"></li> &nbsp;
```

And the Div

```
   <div id="calcShow" class="hide"><br><br><br>
   <?php

                    include("modules/calc/calc.html");
    ?>
   </div>
```

Comment: Just check if `display` is on block, if so give it the `none` element, or just do this using the classes you've made.

Comment: How do I do that exactly? @MartijnEbbens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is create a conditional that checks whether the `<div>` is currently shown or not. Depending on the visibility, change the class that's associated to the `<div>`:

```js
function toggleImg() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('calcShow');
  if (obj.className == 'show') {
    obj.className = 'hide';
  }
  else if (obj.className == 'hide') {
    obj.className = 'show';
  }
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="calcShow" class="hide">Hidden</div>
<br />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100" onclick="toggleImg()">
```

Note that you don't actually have to use classes for this, as this can be done **directly** through the **[`.style.display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** property:

```js
function toggleImg() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('calcShow');
  if (obj.style.display == 'none') {
    obj.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else if (obj.style.display == 'block') {
    obj.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="calcShow" style="display: block">Hidden</div>
<br />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100" onclick="toggleImg()">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Works PERFECT! Thanks so much! I'll approve this post once it lets me.

Comment: No problem; glad to help =]

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Jquery:

**HTML**:

```
<li data-value="iconchange"><img src="modules/icons/icons/calculator.png" width="65" class="calculator"></li> &nbsp;
```

**The DIV**:

```
 <div id="calcShow"><br><br><br>
   <?php

                    include("modules/calc/calc.html");
    ?>
   </div>
```

**The Function:**

```
$('.calculator').click(function{
    var isvisible = $('#calcShow').is(":visible"); 
    if(isvisible == true){
         $('#calcShow').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#calcShow').show();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically one of the easiest way using pure javascript,

```
  function showImage(){
    var obj = document.getElementById('calcShow');

    if(obj.style.display !== "block"){
        obj.style.display = "block";  
    }else{
      obj.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating separate functions for showing and hiding the image, you could create a function that toggles the value. You can use the ternary operator to decide whether you want to set the className to `show` or `hide`.

The ternary operator works like so, `condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse`.

The condition will be `obj.className === "show"`. If this is true, then it should switch from its current value of "show" to a value of "hide". However, if it's false, then it's current value is "hide" and so its new value should be set to "true".

```
function showOrHide() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('calcShow');
    obj.className = (obj.className === "show" ? "hide" : "show");
}
```

Then you can simply set the onClick attribute to call this function.